# How do I set the ntp server of an AWS RDS instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ntp, amazon-rds

This question is in the context of AWS RDS managed databases.

I have an AWS RDS PostgreSQL instance running and I would like it's clock synced to a specific ntp server. How can I do that?

Comment: I'm not sure this is possible. PostgreSQL gets its time from the operating system, and you have no OS access with RDS. I've never seen any reference to NTP access for RDS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Amazon does not provide details about it, but theory says that RDS runs the SQL software on top of moreless standard EC2 instances, both Amazon Linux and Windows Server ones depending on the selected engine, which are placed in specific VPC subnets.

These OS EC2 instances come with NTP client enabled by default, and pick the servers from the VPC DHCP Option Set, which you may tune for your specific needs. Of course, your RDS instances must run in a subnet with internet access if your DHCP Option Set offers public NTP servers.

As I said, AWS does not provide information about NTP in RDS, but given the black-box nature of AWS managed services this is the only logic approach I can figure out: VPC compatible services should honor the VPC DHCP Option Sets.